# Horizontal Icons Popup on bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Horizontal Icons Popup on bootstrap.
How can create a button in Bootstrap when click open popup and shows icon horizontal like this picture (when i click on circle button then open more icon)?

[image]

Comment: Add your example code.

Comment: Can you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? What have you tried so far ? Post a snippet or at least a JSFiddle and we'll help your out

Comment: If you post a question you have also to check your post, if you are not more interested you can delete your post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use drop down buttons, look [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navs/).
Then add the icons inside the `<a></a`> link tags.
last things make the `dropdown-item` inline.

```
 <ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">icon here</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">icon here</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">icon here</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">icon here</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In the link I add there are all the documentation that you need to do it.
have a good time!